# Moving object in only one axis

Tags: objects

I am a near total newb with a frustrating issue. Doing Blender Guru's tutorial making a donut and cup, I am trying to move the saucer in line with the cup/mug. It seems totally easy. I align it properly on the X&Y axes then proceed to move it on the Z using (G)(Z). Confusingly, it also moves forward on the X. I tried not touching the mouse and also hit the two keys at the same time thinking that I am nudging it. Time and again, it moves on multiple axes.

Comment: You've got to know _which_ Z you're constraining to. (Global, Local, Normal, etc) That space is changed in the  Transform Orientation drop-down in the header. Tapping Z _twice_ should always put you in Global coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your using the global axis which is located at the top of your screen in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the information on checking that I'm using Global. The problem persisted regardless. It appears that the issue was that I had 'Snap to' on. With the peek into the fact that there are multiple constraints, I'm working my way through the Udemy Blender Encyclopedia course to see the super basic stuff that I missed by jumping into online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to set the axis you want, and then using the arrow keys the users can nudge along the selected axis?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/160207)